# Why doesn't Vim work with lowercase event names?

Tags: autocmd

From [the Vim event documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#%7Bevent%7D):

> Vim recognizes the following events.  Vim ignores the case of event
>   names (e.g., you can use "BUFread" or "bufread" instead of "BufRead").

So in [my custom_filetype.vim](https://github.com/Gnouc/dot_config_file/blob/master/.vim/custom_filetype.vim#L93), I use `au filetype` to run a command when `FileType` events occur. It worked fine for me until I updated my `vim` to a newer patch level:

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 19 2015 14:09:11)
Included patches: 1-922
Compiled by cuonglm@debian
```

Now `vim` will raise an error with `au filetype`:

```
$ vim
line   93:
E216: No such event: jinja :call Jinja_config()
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Changing any letter in `filetype` to uppercase, like `Filetype`, `fileType` or even `fIletype` worked.

I went through git log but can not find any issues.

Is this change intentional or do I have any mis-configuration?

Comment: can you git-bisect and find the offending patch?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: I try git bisect from patch 900 but the problem still occur. I don't remember the exactly patch before I updated to patch 922. The culprit can also be my plugins updated. I am trying to find what's the real culprit. Do you have the same issue with latest patch? I updated to 930 and the problem still occur.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: It seem that problem came from one of my plugins. If I clean up all the plugins, then left only `au filetype * set bg=dark` in `.vimrc`, it worked fine. Any suggestion to trace this problem?

Comment: Depending on the number of plugins, this can be a tedious task. You would have to disable the plugins one by one and check. I don't know a better way.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: Found the culprit, see my answer for more details. I wonder is that behavior documented else where in vim documentation.

Comment: great for finding the solution. So it's not a vim bug.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: Would you mind explaining how `vim` handle the event name and the augroup name? In user perspective, I think it's common to a user set an augroup name duplicated with vim builtin event name like this issue. I find information in the doc but got no luck.

Comment: sorry, i can't explain this issue. Perhaps Vim should warn in a case like yours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked into the source and I think I found the problem. If you look in the [help](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#:au) (`:h :au`) you will see this:

```
:au[tocmd] [group] {event} {pat} [nested] {cmd}
        Add {cmd} to the list of commands that Vim will
        execute automatically on {event} for a file matching
        {pat} autocmd-patterns.
        Vim always adds the {cmd} after existing autocommands,
        so that the autocommands execute in the order in which
        they were given.  See autocmd-nested for [nested].
```

The problem is the `[group]` part. Your autocommand from your config was this: `au filetype jinja :call Jinja_config()`

This means your `autocmd filetype jinja` will be parsed as an autocommand, belonging to the **filetype** group, using the **jinja** event, which does not exist. Therefore you get that error `E216: No such event: jinja`.

Even when using the `*` as pattern, this would not work as expected, because the `*` would be parsed as meaning **all available events** and the pattern would then be parsed as the first part of your command, which is obviously wrong.

I would suggest opening an issue at the plugins page, that defines that `augroup filetype` as this will cause trouble.

Answer (score 1):

After checking all the plugins, I found the issue due to the [vim-systemtap](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=systemtap.git;a=tree;f=vim;hb=HEAD) plugin, which [define an `augroup` named `filetype`](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=systemtap.git;a=blob;f=vim/ftdetect/stp.vim;h=3be1ca0e3d25283ed3d06beba956eee043b2bffc;hb=HEAD):

```
augroup filetype
  au BufNewFile,BufRead *.stp   set filetype=stp
augroup end
```

It seems that group name would override the event name.